# Alertify.js notification's callback not fired

Tags: alertifyjs

I've got some issues making a callback to be invoked. I prefix that I've followed [this](http://alertifyjs.com/notification/callback.html) link but it won't work right now.

What I need to do is that at the notification click a new page is opened. At the current time, even a simple alert is not shown.

My code is the following

```
 switch (obj.Status) {
 //case "OK":
 //    {
 //        alertify.message(obj.Message, timeout);

 //        break;
 //    }
 case "KO":
 {
     alertify.message(obj.Message, timeout);

     alertify.callback = function () {
     //if(isClicked)
     //    alert('notification dismissed by user');
     //else
     alert('notification auto-dismissed');
     };

     break;
     "Warn":
     //    {
     //        alertify.warning(obj.Message, timeout);

     //        break;
     //    }


     }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

## UPDATE #1

I'm still facing issue passing a value "downstair"

Consider this snippet

```
   chat.client.updateNotifications = function (message) {

                var obj = JSON.parse(message);
                var guid = obj.RequestId;

                var notify = function(level, msg) {
                    var func;
                    switch (level) {
                    case "success":
                        func = alertify.success;
                        break;

                    case "error":
                        func = alertify.error;
                        break;

                    case "warn":
                        func = alertify.warn;
                        break;
                    }

                   

                    var m = func(msg, timeout);
                    m.id = guid;
                    m.callback = function(isClicked) {
                        if (isClicked) {
                            var url = '<%=Url.Action("Index","Import",new {id = -1})%>';
                            url.replace("-1", this.id);

                           // alert(url);
                            window.open(url, "target=_blank");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I got null as id, outside the callback it's ok, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to the provided link, the `callback` is a property of the returned notification object (not `alertify`)

```
//this call returns a notification object. 
var msg = alertify.message('Open up your web console', 10);
//set the callback on the notification object.
msg.callback = function (isClicked) {
  if(isClicked)
    console.log('notification dismissed by user');
  else
    console.log('notification auto-dismissed');
 };
```

Comment: but can I also pass a value ? for example if I need to store a guid that will be passed at the click

Comment: @advapi you can add whatever you want to the `msg` object, the callback is invoked in its context. for example: `msg.callback = function (isClicked) { console.log(this === msg) /* true */ };`